# Risk-Neutral probability deduction

Tags: options, derivatives, risk-neutral-measure

Could anyone show me how to get the second row equation from the first row equation please? For each letter, $p$ is the risk-neutral probability in the risk-neutral world, $u$ is the up factor for the stock, and $d$ is the down factor for the stock, S0 is the beginning stock price. The equation is based on a one-step binomial tree model.
[image]

The textbook referred to is Options, futures, and other derivatives by John Hull 10th.
Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2):

Just expand the term:

\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}(S_T) &= pS_o u + (1 - p)S_0 d \\
&= pS_o u - pS_0 d + S_0 d \\
&= pS_o (u - d) + S_0 d
\end{align}